# branch.io rest API for bulk link creation doesn't preserver order of request

Tags: json, deep-linking, branch.io

We use `POST /v1/url/bulk/:branch_key` for batch deep link generation for some of our items.

The response returns an array of URL's alone. The links are working fine, but its not returned in the order of our items send as request.

Is there any way to identify which branch link belongs to which item? 
At least if the response had item's id or some other custom data returned with it, we could identify the link correctly.

Any hope? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the most basic level, this information is available to you via the Links tab on the Branch dashboard's Liveview & Export page. You can see the last 100 links created on this tab. To see more, you can use the "Export Links" button that appears in the upper right hand corner of the page.

If you need this for more information than can be retrieved via "Export Links," you can have the app whitelisted for the Data Export API (see: https://dev.branch.io/methods-endpoints/data-export-api/guide/). This provides access to a daily collection of .csv files that would include links created and their metadata. To whitelist the app for the Data Export API you send a request to integrations@branch.io. Be sure to include the app's key and to send the request from an email address on the Team tab (https://dashboard.branch.io/settings/team).

You can also query links. For a single link, append "?debug=true" and enter this value into the address bar of your browser.

You can also script the lookup of link data using the HTTP API: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/branch-deep-linking-public-api#viewing-state-of-existing-deep-linking-urls

Answer (score 0):

The Branch API also allows you to specify a custom `alias` (the URL slug), so if you simply want an easy way to tie specific bulk-created URLs to the data inside without querying a second time, you could use this as a workaround. Details [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/#other-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

The bulk creation link API would return the links in that specific order.
You can test out the same via creating 3 links and using a particular parameter to differentiate.

E.G :

```
curl -XPOST https://api2.branch.io/v1/url/bulk/key_live_xxxxxxxxxxx -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '[
    {
      "channel": "facebook",
      "feature": "onboarding",
      "campaign": "new product",
      "stage": "new user",
      "tags": ["one", "two", "three"],
      "data": {
        "$canonical_identifier": "content/123",
        "$og_title": "Title1",
        "$og_description": "Description from Deep Link",
        "$og_image_url": "http://www.lorempixel.com/400/400/",
        "$desktop_url": "http://www.example.com",
        "custom_boolean": true,
        "custom_integer": 1243,
        "custom_string": "everything",
        "custom_array": [1,2,3,4,5,6],
        "custom_object": { "random": "dictionary" }
      }
    },
    {
      "channel": "facebook",
      "feature": "onboarding",
      "campaign": "new product",
      "stage": "new user",
      "tags": ["one", "two", "three"],
      "data": {
        "$canonical_identifier": "content/123",
        "$og_title": "Title2",
        "$og_description": "Description from Deep Link",
        "$og_image_url": "http://www.lorempixel.com/400/400/",
        "$desktop_url": "http://www.example.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "channel": "facebook",
      "feature": "onboarding",
      "campaign": "new product",
      "stage": "new user",
      "tags": ["one", "two", "three"],
      "data": {
        "$canonical_identifier": "content/123",
        "$og_title": "Title3",
        "$og_description": "Description from Deep Link",
        "$og_image_url": "http://www.lorempixel.com/400/400/",
        "$desktop_url": "http://www.example.com"
      }
    }
  ]'
```

As you can see, we have used og_title as a unique parameter and the links created for your app would be in the same order.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can identify link belongs to which item by using data of branch.io link , you can pass branch.io config parameter as well as your custom parameters.
Every Branch link includes a dictionary of key : value pairs that is specified by you at the time the link is created. Branch’s SDKs make this data available within your app whenever the app is opened via a Branch link click.

Comment: We are using REST API, not sdk.
And data is received as [
  {
    "url": "http://xxx.yyy.com/Xyph/exdxCcoxA"
  },
  {
    "url": "http://xxx.yyy.com/Xyph/1xdxCcoxA"
  },
  {
    "url": "http://xxx.yyy.com/Xyph/vxdxCcoxA"
  }
]

Comment: Yes , you can do same for api as well. Just pass custom parameters to data.

Comment: Yes @MayurShah , We are passing custom parameters as well, but returned data contains only URL

Comment: Yes , response of this api is generated link , you got all data whenever user click on branch io link. If user is click with Android device then its open or goto play store with data that you pass into data parameters.

Comment: @KrishNakumR If I solved your problem please accept the answer.